# How to definitively diagnose "load hit store" on AIX PowerPC

Tags: performance, profiling, aix, powerpc

I have optimized my compiler to produce smaller code. However, despite producing fewer instructions and shorter code path, and specifically fewer loads and stores, the code produced for a small demo program is running more slowly.

I suspect the issue is "load hit store". How should I check this? The obvious answer is to profile. Having read through various AIX documentation the answer would seem to be use *tprof* with an appropriate event indicating "load hit store". Something like

```
  tprof -a -usek -E PM_CMPLU_STALL_REJECT -y my_benchmark_program
```

However - this gives the error message

```
  A group with events PM_CMPLU_STALL_REJECT and PM_INST_CMPL cannot be found.
```

The tprof documentation does mention that the chosen event must be in the same group as PM_INST_CMPL. However - it gives no indication of what else to do.

So - how can I test my theory that "load hit store" is the reason for the performance degradation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an AIX expert, but the Knowledge Center says that the "pmlist" command can be used to determine which events are in groups (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/performancetools/eventbasedprofiling.html). Presuming the error message is correct, and these events (PM_CMPLU_STALL_REJECT and PM_INST_CMPL) are not in the same group, you could do two identical runs and record one event during each run, if your benchmark works that way.
Speaking of load-hit-store, do you want to measure PM_CMPLU_STALL_REJECT_LHS event?  (For POWER9, PM_CMPLU_STALL_LHS.)

Comment: The selected event and the event PM_INST_CMPL must both be in an event group for tprof to run. Neither PM_CMPLU_STALL_REJECT, nor PM_CMPLU_STALL_REJECT_LHS  (sensible choice BTW) are in a group with PM_INST_CMPL, meaning it would seem they cannot be measured, and therefore a slowdown due to load-hit-store cannot be measured. That does not seem right.